# Huge fps drop when images have loaded on screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm making a gallery page where the user can just upload images to the website on that page to store them or allow other people to look at them. And I've come across a performance issue and I'm not entirely sure why as I wouldn't have thought it would have any effect on performance.

Here is an image

[image]

The reason I can tell the fps is dropping is because I have a gradient in the background that moves to create an animation/glowing effect.

Here are all relevant pieces of code:

```
    <body class='crt'>

        <script>

            let og_target = null;

            function add_full_image(url, id, element) {
                og_target = element;
                let container = document.getElementById('full-image-container');
                let container_inner = document.getElementById('full-image-container-inner');
                let pre_img = document.getElementById(id);
                container.style.zIndex = '1';
                container.classList.remove('hidden');
                container_inner.removeChild(container_inner.lastChild);
                let img = document.getElementById(id).cloneNode(false);
                img.className = 'full-image';
                container_inner.appendChild(img);
            }

            document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                let container_inner = document.getElementById('full-image-container-inner');
                let container = document.getElementById('full-image-container');
                const outside_click = typeof event.composedPath === 'function' &&  !event.composedPath().includes(container_inner);
                const on_target = typeof event.composedPath === 'function' &&  event.composedPath().includes(og_target);
                console.log(outside_click, container.classList.contains('hidden'), container_inner.children.length);

                if (outside_click && !on_target && !container.classList.contains('hidden') && container_inner.children.length > 0) {
                    container.classList.add('hidden');
                }
            });
        </script>

        <div class='background-layer-1'> </div>
        <div class='background-layer-2'> </div>
        <div id='full-image-container' class='full-image-container'>
            <div id='full-image-container-inner'>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='gallery-grid'>
            % for i, image in enumerate(images):
                <a href='#' class='gallery-image' onclick='add_full_image("/user_data/gallery/{{image[1]}}", "{{i}}", this)'>
                    <img id='{{i}}' src="/user_data/gallery/{{image[1]}}" loading='lazy'/>
                </a>
            % end
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
.background-layer-1 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(29, 42, 52) 0%, rgba(20,20,31,1) 25%, rgb(25, 26, 42) 80%, rgb(28, 41, 47) 100%);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    animation: gradient 10s ease infinite;

    height: 100%;
}

.background-layer-2 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    background: linear-gradient(127deg, rgba(50, 114, 55, 0.4) 0% , rgba(20, 20, 31, 0.4) 25%, rgba(25, 26, 42, 0.4) 70%, rgba(95, 66, 185, 0.4) 100%);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    animation: 10s 4s ease infinite gradient, 5s forwards background_layer_2;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```
.crt::after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(18, 16, 16, 0.1);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    pointer-events: none;
    animation: flicker 0.15s infinite;
}

.crt::before {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(18, 16, 16, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.06), rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.02), rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.06));
    z-index: 2;
    background-size: 100% 2px, 3px 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```
@keyframes flicker {
    0% { opacity: 0.27861; }
    5% { opacity: 0.34769; }
    10% { opacity: 0.23604; }
    15% { opacity: 0.90626; }
    20% { opacity: 0.18128; }
    25% { opacity: 0.83891; }
    30% { opacity: 0.65583; }
    35% { opacity: 0.67807; }
    40% { opacity: 0.26559; }
    45% { opacity: 0.84693; }
    50% { opacity: 0.96019; }
    55% { opacity: 0.08594; }
    60% { opacity: 0.20313; }
    65% { opacity: 0.71988; }
    70% { opacity: 0.53455; }
    75% { opacity: 0.37288; }
    80% { opacity: 0.71428; }
    85% { opacity: 0.70419; }
    90% { opacity: 0.7003; }
    95% { opacity: 0.36108; }
    100% { opacity: 0.24387; }
}
```

```
@keyframes gradient {
    0% { background-position: 0% 50%; }
    50% { background-position: 100% 50%; }
    100% { background-position: 0% 50%; }
}
```

I've included everything that I think could have an affect on the fps.

I set the image loading to lazy to force them to load after everything else has loaded to not create any extra delay when initially loading the page. I've tried removing different things but it seems to only be the amount of images that load that have an effect on the fps so I'm wondering if there is something I can do to fix it.

Also the lines starting with `%` are python lines

Comment: Not really answering you, but did you know that browsers' DevTools have tools to help with this? They may help you a lot in understanding this behavior. I highly recommend reading [this](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/performance/)

Comment: And how different is this problem without the CSS animation in the background?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius its still as bad with or without the background effects

Comment: In order to reproduce the effect of which you speak we would need to use the same/similar images - how large are they?

Comment: fps can drop when loading many things at once, especially when animating them. Images and <canvas> are prone to this. It is also obv dependent on hardware and it also depends on front- vs back-end. Note that when it comes to front-end, the client's browsers (afaik all of them) are only allowed to use 1 CPU-thread to calculate and render stuff.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius there are 6 images which i uploaded to the site twice when it started lagging, they are about 3, 2, 4.5, 1, 4 and 1mb in size, and theyre all 4k images but resized down to about 250 pixels width and height since theyre 1:1.

Comment: I've edited it with a screenshot now

Comment: running this with some random 4k images with all animations causes Chromes CPU usage to go off the scale - settling around 150%. With no animations that drops to near zero once loaded. You are asking a lot with all the opacity changes

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I've tried removing all the animations and the CPU usage is still high, there has to be a way for me to improve the performance of just the images being rendered because I've tested now in multiple different conditions and the images are the only common denominator